# Cannot install brownie with pipx

Tags: brownie, pipx

I struggle to install brownie it is impossible to do so even with the command line `pipx install eth-brownie`. It prints me this error, however I have nothing to to with it because it's an automatic things (It is not my code wich is being executed).

Do you have an idea to install brownie or resolve this problem?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\*****\appdata\roaming\python\python310\scripts\pipx.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 779, in cli
    return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command
    return commands.install(
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
    venv.install_package(
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
    subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
  File "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
    print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

use 1.pip install brownie and after that
2.pip install eth-brownie